# Return first order by each month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to modify my current query to return the first order for each month in each year.

Here is my full table and my current query.

```
select orderdate, sum(UnitPrice*Qty) 
AS month_firstOrder_total
from OrderByDate
group by OrderDate
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    select *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(orderdate), MONTH(orderdate) ORDER BY orderdate ASC) rn
    from OrderByDate
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
WHERE rn = 1;
```

You can get the total sum per order date if you want, too:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    select *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(orderdate), MONTH(orderdate) ORDER BY orderdate ASC) rn
          ,sum(UnitPrice*Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY orderdate) as sum_qty
    from OrderByDate
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: thanks for clear answer.
I am wondering if it's possible to use sub-query instead of using windows-function?

Comment: @Aiden For calculating the `SUM` you can use a sub-query. Then join by `order_date` and unite the results. After that, you still need to execute `ROW_NUMBER` or other ranking function in order to mark the first row of each group.

Comment: is it possible to use something like Group By, TOP, Order By OrderDate ASC to get the first row of each group? I was stuck how to combine these stuff...

Comment: @Aiden Yes, you can but it won't be so clear. First, calculated the first order for each month-year pairs. This can be done using `MIN(order_date)` with `GROUP BY YEAR(), MONTH()`. Then, using `cross apply` select all `orders` matching your order date and calculated the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a MONTH column?

Then you select Min(id) and order by MONTH.

I just guess

```
select *
from 
    (select min(id), month, sum(UnitPrice * Qty) 
     from your_table_name
     group by month)
```

Comment: thanks for response. If we group by month then it would not separate 2018 and 2017.

Comment: Then add the year; SELECT datepart(yyyy,orderdate) *100 +datepart(mm,orderdate) as ordermonth